# Dictionary of Lists: Sort lists and maintain relative index position

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an OrderedDict of lists, for example:

```
data = OrderedDict([('a', [3, 2, 1]]), ('b', [z, y, x])])
```

I would like to sort both lists by data['a']. The result would look like:

```
OrderedDict([('a', [1, 2, 3]]), ('b', [x, y, z])])
```

where the elements maintain *relative* index position across all lists.

I can do it by tracking the indices:

```
sorted_data = sorted([(t, i) for t, i in zip(data['a'],range(len(data['a'])))])
```

but that requires another loop to sort out the other column(s). This example is shortened - there are many more dictionary entries. Is there a more Pythonic way to do this, say with operator.itemgetter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take my own answer for now, until someone submits something more refined. This is my solution but seems clunky:

```
sortedData = sorted([(t, i) for t, i in zip(data['a'],range(len(data['a'])))])
sortedIndex = [i[1] for i in sortedData]
for key in data.keys():
    data[key] = [ data[key][i] for i in sortedIndex]
```